# nodeJs sequelize как избавиться от дубликатов при параллельной записи

Tags: node.js, cluster, node-redis, sequelize.js

Всем привет!

в базе есть таблица `translate` вида id, language, text
поле id не автоинкрементное и одинаково для перевода одной фразы в разных языках
есть скрипт на NodeJs с использованием express, cluster(в данный момент работает только 1 воркер), sequelize в кластере подсоединяется клиент Redis

скрипт принимает на вход **sourceLang, tergetLang, phraseToTranslate**

если данной фразы нет в базе - то делается запрос к googleTranslateApi этой фразы для всех языков которые существуют в базе

после этого проверяется максимальный id в кеше и базе, инкрементится и снова сохраняется в кеш.

зарезервированный id присваивается данной фразе и после этого пишется в базу

проблемма такая
при одиночных тестовых обращениях к скрипту всё проходит нормально, 
НО если отправить в скрипт большое количество запросов - то разным фразам часто присваиваются одинаковые id

На сколько я понимаю - сервер парралельно отвечает на несколько запросов и тем самым получает одинаковые maxId - как этого избежать?

должно быть по три id в данном случае - так-как языка только три
[image: пример данных с повторяющимися id]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Последовательные суррогатные числовые ключи не нужны!

---

Давайте для начала разберемся с общепринятым подходом к локализации.

Традиционно, при локализации используется **строка-ключ** и один или несколько переводов для этой строки. В качестве ключа обычно используются либо строка на основном естественном языке (чаще всего английский). Эта строка-ключ может содержать в себе ноль или более шаблонов, куда подставляются реальные значения. Например, в вашей системе может быть вот такая локализационная константа:

```
Hello %s!
```

Которая может иметь следующие переводы:

```
RU: Привет %s!
ES: ¡Hola %s!
```

Типовая схема хранения переводов имеет вид:

```
lang | key       | trans
-----+-----------+-----------
RU   | Hello %s! | Привет %s!
ES   | Hello %s! | ¡Hola %s!
```

К чему я все это рассказываю? К тому, что Вы упускаете из вида один очень важный момент: вам **не нужен** суррогатный ключ (ваше поле `id`) для работы с локализационными константами. Вместо него правильнее использовать естественный ключ - переводимую строку. Дополнительно стоит ввести на уровне БД уникальный ключ `(язык + переводимая строка)`.

Это позволит с одной стороны выкинуть лишенный смысла числовой ключ из БД, а с другой упростить процесс перевода и использовать строки естественного языка в коде приложения. Например, [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) использует вот такой формат:

```
console.log(_('Hello %s!', 'John Doe'));
```

<sub>Если я вас не убедил, читайте дальше.</sub>

---

Процесс получения элементов числовой последовательности в распределенной системе - весьма трудная задача. Лично я знаю всего два приемлемых способа ее решения:

1. Реализовать централизованный сервис, выдающий элементы последовательности
2. Отказаться от последовательности и использовать в качестве идентификаторов [Глобально-Уникальные Идентификаторы (UUID)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID).

Первый путь описывать не хочу, поскольку он достаточно сложен в отказоустойчивой/масштабируемой реализации (у вас, например, не получилось). Вместо этого я расскажу подробнее про UUID.

Основная идея UUID - использование значений с высокой уникальностью в качестве идентификаторов. При этом подходе вам не нужен централизованный сервис генерирующий ID записей - клиенты сами генерируют столько идентификаторов, сколько нужно, не боясь при этом конфликтов. Сейчас существует 5 различных стандартов генерации UUID (все они описаны в [RFC4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)). Я бы обратил ваше внимание на UUIDv4 - поскольку именно он полностью уникален и не зависит от окружения, в котором происходит генерация.

Что касается node.js, то в экосистеме npm есть модуль [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) который позаботиться об уникальности генерируемых значений.

С использованием этого подхода алгоритм работы вашего приложения может иметь вид:

1. На вход метода поступает набор из исходного языка (`sourceLang`), массива целевых языков (`targetLang`), строки, которую надо перевести (`phraseToTranslate`).
2. Генерируется `UUID`
3. Исходная строка с добавлением `UUID` записываются в базу данных.
4. Исходное задание разбивается на несколько, для каждого из них задается ключ из `phraseToTranslate` + `targetLang` + `UUID`
5. По мере выполнения заданий перевода, в базу записываются переведенные фразы. При этом используется `UUID` из п.2.

Comment: Если использовать "типовую схему" которую вы описали - например для получения перевода с **sourceLang=ru, targetLang=fr, phraseToTranslate = текст** то получается мне нужно сначала получить **"key"** а после уже если нашли - искать **trans** - я правильно вас понял?
  P.S. про уникальные неинкрементированные id я тоже задумывался но думал что есть какой-то более правильный способ инкрементить id без дублей. если разрешат избавиться от id вообще - так и сделаю, если нет - буду использовать модуль uuid В любом случае огромное спасибо.

Comment: @LeoMrakobes обычно выбирают один естественный язык в качестве исходного. Часто это английский. В качестве альтернативы можно использовать некие абстрактные константы в качестве ключей. Для примера из ответа это может быть `hello_message`. Собственно именно эти ключи (+ язык) и используются для выбора переводов. Но тут все очень сильно зависит от того, как именно вы используете эти переводы в приложении.